# Print & Submit to insert into databse in same page in same submit button

Tags: php, mysql

My Form

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div id="mydiv">
<tr>
<td>Service Provider & Type</td>
<td><?php echo $row['cab_name'];?></td>
<td>Name</td>
<td><?php echo $_SESSION['name'];?></td>
</tr>
    <input type="submit" value="Print" onClick="PrintElem('#mydiv')" style="border:0px;" class="submit" />
</div>

</form>
```

action page

```
$booker_name=$_POST['name'];
$service_provider=$_POST['cab_name'];

$sql="INSERT INTO ticket_details(booker_name,
service_provider) values('$booker_name','$service_provider')";
```

Here, i want to print the div also with submit the data to insert into database in the same page.. But when i press the print button , it's giving me print option along with it's also inserting the values to DB but the problem is simultaneously the page is automatically getting refreshed &  the null values are also inserting & in some fields in the page its giving me undefined index error after the page got refreshed . i knw this problem occures due to giving the acton in same page but i ve to do this.. any idea to overcome this situation ??

Answer (score 0):

So... the data should only be inserted when the form is submitted, you have to wrap your insert in some conditional statement eg..

set a hidden value

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="form_submitted">
```

wrap your insert code in an if statement

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'form_submitted'){
YOUR INSERT CODE
}
```

This is a bit crude but should help you get the idea